# Compute $\int_0^{1/2} (\arcsin(x))^2 dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Compute $\displaystyle \int_0^{1/2} (\arcsin(x))^2 dx$

My attempt is this

[image]

Comment: You have the wrong limit of the integral, $\sin \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac12$. There may be mistakes in the following or not.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Integrate by parts taking $u=(\arcsin{x})^2$ and $\mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{d}x$.

$\displaystyle \int (\arcsin(x))^2 \mathrm{d}x = x(\arcsin{x})^2 - 2\int\frac{x\arcsin{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Integrate by parts again taking $u=\arcsin{x}$ and $\displaystyle{\mathrm{d}v=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\mathrm{d}x$

Then we have $$\Biggl|2\sqrt{1-x^2}\arcsin{x} + x(\arcsin{x})^2 - 2x\Biggr|^{1\over2}_0= \frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{6}+ \frac{\pi^2}{72} -1$$